# How to push extra text to 'select' label in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `select_field` on a form such as:

```
<%= f.select(:task_id, Task.all.collect {|p| [p.name, p.id]},  {prompt: "Select"}, {class: 'form-control', required: true}) %>
```

The generated HTML is:

```
<select class="form-control" required="required" name="company[task_id]" id="company_task_id">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="3">Site Management</option>
    <option value="1">Real Estate</option>
    <option value="2">Meeting</option>
    <option value="4">Training</option>
</select>
```

I want to add some extra text to the label such as:

- `Site Management (ABC)`
- `Real Estate (ABC)`
- `Meeting (ABC)`
- `Training (ABC)`

How do I add `(ABC)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a method in the `Task` model which will do that for you

```
#task.rb
def name_with_abc
  "#{self.name}" + "(ABC)"
end
```

And now change the `select` to

```
<%= f.select(:task_id, Task.all.collect {|p| [p.name_with_abc, p.id]},  {prompt: "Select"}, {class: 'form-control', required: true}) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

For more organised way It can be done as : -

in controller -

```
@tasks_options = Task.distinct.pluck(<<-PLUCK, :id)
                   CONCAT_WS("", tasks.name, " (ABC)")
                 PLUCK
```

which will fire a sql query

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("", tasks.name, "(ABC)"), `tasks`.`id` FROM `tasks`
```

In view

```
<%= f.select(:task_id, @tasks_options,  {prompt: "Select"}, {class: 'form-control', required: true}) %>
```

So instead of using collect which will iterate each element of array , this can be better solution.

Comment: Solution is working but Pavan's answer is more organized +1

Comment: @jesica Hi, Can you please check the updated answer, i think this can be better solution in context of organised way and for better loading all options rather than using `collect`. that's a bit difference of what answer you have accepted. :) just tested it now and it's working fine at my end. let me know for any further guidance or changes

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select(:task_id, Task.all.collect {|p| ["#{p.name} (ABC)", p.id]},  {prompt: "Select"}, {class: 'form-control', required: true}) %>
```